# Windows 10 UWP StackPanel Visibility not working

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-10-universal

I have a Windows 10 UWP app and in my XAML, I have a StackPanel that is used to show a progress bar. So, by default, the StackPanel visibility is set to collapsed. Then, in my code behind, I am trying to set the visibility to visible when the user clicks a button and after, I call a method to do some processing. With this example, the panel never shows.

```
    private void BtnProcess_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the progress panel to visible
        toggleProgressPanel(true);
        //This is a long running process that can take 3-5 seconds.
        ProcessRequest();
        //Hide the progress panel
        toggleProgressPanel(false);
    }

    private void toggleProgressPanel(bool show)
    {
        pnlProgressBar.Visibility = show ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

One thing I noticed during testing is that if I comment out the ProcessRequest call and obviously the hiding of the progress panel, it will show up at that point. I also tried showing and hiding the panel inside of the ProcessRequest method call, showing it at the very beginning of the method and collapsing it at the very end.

I verified that the long running method process does in fact take 3-5 seconds to execute so it isn't that it is hiding the panel so fast that you never see it.

It almost seems like it is a UI refresh issue but I am not sure how to fix it. It seems because the calling method, BtnProcess_OnClick is doing all of it, the UI never actually refreshes until the BtnProcess_OnClick method is complete and returns and that is why it never shows. Is that correct? How do you work around this if it is the case?

I am reluctant to put the ProcessRequest method call inside of a Task.Run because that method does need to do a fair amount of interaction with the UI and that solution would put it on a different thread which means I would have to write a fair amount of code (I think) to then work around that. It seems there must be an easy solution I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: ProcessRequest() should be async method.

Comment: @Archana Thank you for the response. So, if it is async, I can still access all of my UI because I am not technically on another thread, which is good. The reason I did not do this is because nothing in that method is awaitable. From what I understand, even if I make the method async, if there is nothing awaited inside the method, it will still run sync. Is that okay or do I also need to add an abritrary await Task.Delay(100); or something like that to force an await?

Comment: If its taking 3-5 seconds, that would be enough. Now your blocking UI for 3-4 seconds, so whatever changes you make to visibility wont be reflected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per recommendation of Archana, I made my method call to ProcessRequest async. However, I don't have anything that is awaitable inside of that method. So, just marking the method signature as async without an awaitable makes it still run synchronously (from what I understand). So, to force it to run async, I added the following inside of my method as well as marking it async:

```
await Task.Delay(50);
```

This is just a small delay that is hardly noticeable but also gives me something that is awaitable inside of the method.

Then, I also changed the caller of this method, in my case the button press event and made it async as well and had it await the call to the method.

Now, it works as expected and my UI is updated each time. Here is the complete code:

```
private async void BtnProcess_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Set the progress panel to visible
    toggleProgressPanel(true);
    //This is a long running process that can take 3-5 seconds.
    await ProcessRequest();
    //Hide the progress panel
    toggleProgressPanel(false);
}

private void toggleProgressPanel(bool show)
{
    pnlProgressBar.Visibility = show ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private async Task ProcessRequest()
{
    await Task.Delay(50);
    //Now do all of my long running code here
}
```

Doing all of this allows control to return back to the caller of my long running method, in my case the button press event, while the long running method of ProcessRequest keeps working async. By returning control back to the caller, it can complete and allow the UI to update.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Try putting your long run task into a `await Task.Run(() => ProcessRequest());` rather than a hardcoded delay like that.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If you look at the last paragraph on my OP, I mentioned that as an option but that I was reluctant to do it because my ProcessRequest method that is called has a fair amount of work that it does on the UI and UI controls. Task.Run forces the method to run on another thread so I would have to change things significantly or add a fair amount of code in the method to sync back to the UI thread with dispatchers every time I want to access the UI. Seems like a pain unless I am missing something.